# Full-screen goes out when switching to portrait

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I am using Youtube API for android app and I'm looking for a way to avoid exiting full-screen mode while switching between landscape modes. Meaning, I don't want to exit full-screen mode while switching the phone to portrait mode. I need the video to always be on full-screen.

Is there a way to make it happen?

My current code for full screen is:

```
@Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
            YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String Video_Link = intent.getStringExtra("youtube_id");
            player.cueVideo(Video_Link);
            player.setFullscreen(true);
        }
    }
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On an orientation change, the onCreate method is called. You could try adding this line within the Activity in question in your Manifest file to prevent the onCreate call.

```
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|layoutDirection"
```

and it might maintain the fullscreen status of youtube for you...

otherwise you might try overriding the onconfigchange method:

```
@Override //reconfigure display properties on screen rotation
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

            //Checks the orientation of the screen
            if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) 
                {
                // handle change here
                } 
            else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
                {
                // or here
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In my situation the activity needed to be in portrait orientation but the video in landscape at all times.

As Will Thomson mentioned above you'll want to add this to your manifest:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

This may not be the ideal way to do things but does what I need.
You can set a fullscreen listener after initialization:

```
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {

    this.player = player;
    player.setOnFullscreenListener(this);

    if(!wasRestored) {
        player.cueVideo(Constants.INTO_YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID);
    }
}
```

Then in the callback you can manually set the orientation:

```
@Override
public void onFullscreen(boolean fullscreen) { 

    videoIsFullScreen = fullscreen;

    if(fullscreen) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }
    else {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
}
```

When the user taps play you can use `player.setFullscreen(true)`. When the user taps the back button you can exit fullscreen or finish the activity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(player != null && videoIsFullScreen) {
        player.setFullscreen(false);
    }
    else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

There's another similar answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39494759/1159930 but following the first comment played the video in fullscreen portrait mode rather than landscape.